# Executing an SQL Script in a File

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Stored Procedure that needs to execute a script that is on the Windows file system - 'C:\test.sql'.

Is there an easy way to execute this script from my Stored Procedure?

On the net I've seen some suggestions to use xp_cmdshell & sqlcmd but do I have to go down to the DOS command line to run an sql script from SQL Server?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir /b "C:\test.sql"'

dir/b lists the files in the folder
```